# javascript multi-line strings gives Javascript ILLEGAL Token error; How to solve this?

Tags: javascript, php

I have below code in php

```
<? php 

   $articleContent = "  Blah ..
                        The game is on 
                        Foo ";
?>
```

Also I have below JavaScript Code Also

```
<script>

  var articleContent = "{$articleContent}";  // from php     
  /* I WANT TO USE THIS  articleContent variable , but it cannot take it , it displays a ILLEGAL token error due to multi line string !*/
</script>
```

Comment: Well yes, because that's a syntax error in JS. Have you tried using backticks ` instead of double quotes? (ES6 [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).)

Comment: JSON encode your PHP variable.

Comment: How to add those backticks ? is it from php code or can be done in JS ?

Comment: `json_encode` will solve your problem. In javacript use `var articleContent = <?php echo json_encode($articleContent) ?>`. No need to append Quotes , it'll do it by itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Try my code

```
<?php 

   $articleContent = '  Blah ..
                        The game is on 
                        Foo ';

?>

<script>
  var articleContent = <?php echo json_encode($articleContent); ?>     
  alert(articleContent);
</script>
```

Comment: But...the `$articleContent` variable has line breaks in it...

Comment: I think shortest path is this " var articleContent = <?php echo json_encode($articleContent); ?> "

Comment: @BhavinSasapra it's working with me :)

Comment: @BhavinSasapra I have added code to your answer try it. thank you :)